# Solve equation for z

Tags: analysis, finance

I am unable to isolate the variable $z$ in the following equation and cannot solve for it. Is it even possible? If so how?

$$B = \frac{R}{z} (1-(1+z)^{-L})$$

I want to, in general, be able to fine the interest rate that corresponds to an annuity. Whoever changed my equation in LaTex forgot to put the -L as an exponent and made it less easy to interpet by simplyfing.
L = maturity, 
B = present value of the annuity, 
z = interest-rate/period, 
R = payment/period.

Comment: Please type out the equation in MathJax to make it more readable.

Comment: So, are you after the rate/period (the $z$)?

Comment: @NoChance yes, eaxctly

Comment: It would help if you say what variables mean and which variables you know.

Comment: I want to, in general, be able to fine the interest rate that corresponds to an annuity. Whoever changed my equation in LaTex forgot to put the -L as an exponent. L = maturity, B = present value of the annuity, z = interest-rate/period, R = payment/period.

Comment: The original version had this expression: B = R/z * ( 1 - (1+z)^-L ) - How is that different from what you now have? @GEdgar has fixed it now I guess.

Comment: The exponent is $-L$.  The first TeX version ended up with exponent "$-$" not including the $L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the present value $B$, for an annuity of $L$ years with interest rate $z$ and payments $R$ is

$$
B=R\,a_{\overline{L}|z}=R\frac{1-(1+z)^{-L}}{z}
$$
and it can only be solved numerically to find $z$.